# List of all dpkg exit status

Tags: dpkg

Is there a list/page/manual where all the **dpkg exit status** are explained? The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) doesn't seem to cover it.

Comment: Most users don't need the exit code - a more useful error message is generated by most errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in dpkg source:

[errors.c](https://github.com/davidben/dpkg/blob/tarfile-proof-of-concept/src/errors.c) uses `<errno.h>`

`errno` error codes can be found [here](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno)